# conditionally update column with Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

all! I'm trying to update a column with data from another table, but only in specific cases.
That is what I'm trying:

```
UPDATE table_name1 
SET id = case 
            when (select code from table_name2 where condition1) = 'special value' (here I'll have many result records)
            then (select id from table_name3 where condition2) (here I'll have many result records)
            else (select id from table_name3 where condition3) (here I'll have many result records)
         end;
```

Is it possible to do something like this or maybe I should use loops? I want to update all entries with one query. Thanks for all answers in advance!

Comment: yes as long your select return only one value

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; a complete description of the (minimal example of the) problem; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output for your sample data.